# Getting error in _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method in .net core 3

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity, cookie-authentication

I am using **CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme**.

When I try to use   **signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync** method,I am getting this error===>

**cookie.Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead.**

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

In [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookie-based-authentication), you can find that achieve cookie-based authentication in ASP.NET Core app, we can select **one of the two options** below.

1. [Use cookies with Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services)
2. [Use cookies without Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Firstly, it seems that you mix/configure both two options in one app. And if you specified `options.Cookie.Expiration`, which would cause this issue.

```
// code of configure Identity service

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
        //....
    });

//...
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will check and let you know.